# Base De Datos En Modo Suspect

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

SQL Server 2017 Management Studio

se me presenta un error en la base de datos del sistema aparece en modo suspect

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

tengo la siguiente consulta

```
EXEC sp_resetstatus msdb; 

ALTER DATABASE msdb SET EMERGENCY DBCC checkdb(msdb) 

ALTER DATABASE msdb 
SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE DBCC CheckDB (msdb, REPAIR_ALLOW_DATA_LOSS) 

ALTER DATABASE msdb SET MULTI_USER
```

al ejecutar la consulta me aparece el siguiente error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Sugerencia: siempre indica en tu pregunta qué motor y qué versión estás usando para que la ayuda sea más efectiva. Esta vez te ayudé añadiendo las etiquetas correspondientes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para ese error, tienes dos opciones:

- Restaurar msdb de un backup que tengas
- volverla a crear

Para la segunda opción, en MSSQL Server 2008 y posteriores se puede recrear la bd a partir de unas plantillas que están en el subdirectorio `Binn\Templates`, que es sólo copiarlas y pegarlas en donde están los archivos dañados, reemplazándolos (habiendo detenido el servicio de MSSQL previamente, por supuesto).

Si no están, esa tarea toma más tiempo, pues es necesario ésto:

- Desvincula la msdb dañada. No puede hacerse como con otras BD por ser una bd del sistema; es posible si se inicia el servidor con la *trace flag* 3608. Se puede hacer esto deteniendo el servidor, navegando al directorio  `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\Bin` (o similar) y ejecutando: `start sqlservr.exe -c -T3608`
- Mover o renombrar los archivos dañados de msdb (`msdbdata.mdf` y `msdblog.ldf` en el directorio `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\Data` o similar)
- Correr el script `instmsdb.sql` en el directorio `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\Install`
- Detener el servidor y reiniciarlo normal (desde el servicio, por ejemplo, sin *trace flags*)

PD. La versión del Sql Server Management Studio no es lo mismo que la versión del motor de base de datos MS SQL Server que tengas. Tu imagen da una pista pues el servidor reporta la construcción 10.50.1600, que puedes buscar y ver que es MSSQL Server 2008.